# jquery not updating dom inside hide complete function

Tags: jquery

I have a pair of Jquery / Javascript functions:

```
var id_testimonials = jQuery.noConflict();

//recusive function to power slider
function ttd_testimonial (elem) {

    elem.each (function () {
        if(id_testimonials(this).is(':visible')) {
            id_testimonials(this).hide(4000, function () {ttd_show (id_testimonials(this)); });

        }
    });
}

//figure out what to show
function ttd_show (elem) {
    container = elem.parent();

    if (elem.next().length !== 0) {
        next_elem = elem.next();
    } else {
        next_elem = container('.testimonial_single').first();
    }


    regen_elems = container('.testimonial_single');
    id_testimonials(next_elem).show(4000, function (){ ttd_testimonial(regen_elems); });
}
```

The complete function on the `.hide()` fires correctly as far as I can see. I am also able to select the `next_elem` variable correctly, so I know the second function is receiving it's args correctly.

However, the `.show()` never fires (or never seems to). There doesn't seem to be any reason for this.

I have tried `next_elem.show(args)`, `next_elem.show()` and `id_testimonials(next_elem).show()`  with no effect.

Also when I try adding `.css()` in the second function the dom is not updated, but I can `alert()` object properties correctly. Obviously the two things are linked but I can't work out the cause.

[JsFiddle as requested](http://jsfiddle.net/MBEvW/)

Comment: Could you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't get the intent in `container('.testimonial_single')`. container isn't a function.

Comment: A big part of jQuery is the ability to write more concise code. `var id_testimonials = jQuery.noConflict();` seems to go against that purpose.

Comment: It is all a bit cryptic, but container is actually a jQuery object, initialized in `container = elem.parent();` with  `elem` being the argument in `ttd_show()`, passed as `$(this)` essentially. For some reason th OP uses `id_testimonials` instead of `$`. ... I quite agree with dystroy: jQuery stands for "write less, do more!"

Comment: I am having conflicts between jquery and other javascript libraries. I don't like having multiple libraries, but I don't have much choice.

Comment: To improve readability, maybe you could do `var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();` instead. That makes it more obvious when you use functions like `jQ(this)`?

Comment: @user2641562 You didn't answer the point about `container('.testimonial_single')`. A jQuery object isn't a function. What did you try to do ? Did you mean `id_testimonials` instead of `container` ?

Comment: @dystroy `container('.testimonial_single')` is for getting child elements of the container object. It's just a standard `$('.class')` selecter

Comment: @user2641562 Look at your console : Uncaught TypeError: Property 'container' of object [object Object] is not a function. Use `container.find` here.

Comment: @user2641562 again, `container.find()` will work, but it is not very easy to read/follow/understand and does not necessarily reflect the underlying logic. In this case you are using a standard class selector without referencing anything from the particular `container`object. So, `jQ('.testimonial_single')` would have been a much clearer statement.

Comment: @dystroy that's fixed it. Care to add an answer for me to tick? I should of seen that error. Also I'll keep the readability advice in mind for the future.

Comment: @cars10 I wrote it like that to keep it portable, but to be honest know that I think about it, that didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this error in the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'container' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

That's because `container` is a jQuery object, which isn't a function. You must use jQuery traversal functions like `find` to get your elements starting from some context.

Replace

```
container('.testimonial_single')
```

with

```
container.find('.testimonial_single')
```